# Network connection when receiving/making a call

Tags: android, mobile, call, network-protocols, dtmf

Is there any way to maintain Network connection when receiving or making a call using Android mobile?

Data connection losses when receiving or making a voice call from my device. I am working with an application that need to maintain network connectivity during the call time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using your phone data Network connection then phone will drop data connection as networks can't handle data and voice simultaneously.

This problem can be resolved if you use wi-fi connection.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your mobile network type.

GPRS service has 3 classes: A/B/C

1. GPRS Class A: data connection and voice are available at the same time
2. GPRS Class B: data connection disconnected when calling
3. GPRS Class C: data connection only, no voice service

Maybe you are using Class B.